# Storyboard apps also run on pre-iOS 5 devices?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, ios5

If an app is developed using Storyboard in Xcode 4.2, can this app run in iOS 4.x devices?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it can't. Storyboards are only available in iOS 5.

From the [UIStoryboard class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Available in iOS 5.0 and later

From [Converting to Storyboards Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/_index.html):

> Storyboarding is a new way to create user interfaces for iOS applications, beginning with iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2.